# To integrate a trained machine learning model with react native app

Tags: react-native, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity, pre-trained-model

I have an FYP project (a social media app like Instagram) that requires me to create a simple recommendation system. I've trained my dataset on cosine similarity using Python, but I'm at a loss on what to do next. How can I integrate my trained ml model to React native or if there is a better and easier way to make a recommendation system?

I tried reading documentation and watching videos. But I still don't seem to be able to grasp some difficult concepts. I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me instructions or steps on what to learn after training my model. Or if I have to use some library or packages etc. [not sure if this is the appropriate forum for this inquiry]

Comment: One way I did was to create a python server and get my react native app to send a request to the python server and get the results back.

Comment: thanks alot...I will try using your method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, convert your AI model to tflite model using TensorFlow Lite convertor, then install the necessary packages like tensorflow.js and tfjs-tflite using yarn/npm. Once done, I presume you are predicting images so I have made a sample code for this:

```js
const classifyImage = async (image) => {
    const image = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
    const model = await mobilenet.load();
    const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image).resizeNearestNeighbor([224, 224]).toFloat();
    const predictions = await model.classify(tensor);
    setPredictions(predictions);
};
```